# Blender stops halfway when baking textures

Tags: texture-baking

I'm trying to bake multiple materials into one texture map. As you can see in the image, I've selected all the objects that I want to bake the materials, selected the image texture that I want the materials to be baked on in the node editor, and made sure the bake setting is set to diffuse and unticked the direct&indirect options. Blender only bakes the two textures that you can see on the upper left of the image attached, and then stops baking. The image resolution is 4K and I have UV unwrapped all selected objects. I'm not sure why this happens or how to fix it.
Anyone have any idea why this is happening? [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you need to go to the *Object Data* tab, inside the *Properties* panel, under *UV maps* you have to click the + button to add a new UV map to your object and name it something, for example, *bake*. Then repeat the process for each one of the objects you want to appear in the image texture after the bake process (remember that all the newly created UV maps must have the same name and have them selected for all the objects). Before you proceed to bake the texture, you also need to unwrap all your objects at once.